# re not working python; think my grep is to blame.

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, grep

I'm taking a class in which we had to install GNU grep and make it our default grep version (I'm using a Mac, if this is relevant).  I think this was a mistake, because now I am trying to use the re module in Python and simple things like

```
re.findall("abc", "a")
re.findall("8/24/2014", "[0-9]+")
```

return the empty list.  Is this a known bug with re, and regardless, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: don't know how gnu grep and python are related.

Comment: @AvinashRaj they are not but you need something to put the blame on in cases like this. There was a mistake, someone else must have make it.

Answer (score 1):

Its just the order of arguments that you are passing wrongly. Try:

```
>>> re.findall("a", "abc")
['a']
>>> re.findall("[0-9]+", "8/24/2014")
['8', '24', '2014']
```

..And there's no problem with `grep` -- [Python's re module implements its own Regex matcher](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a82fc1f366b4/Modules/_sre.c).